# Changing a property in a Collection

Tags: javascript, collections

I'm trying to convert a property in a Collection. In this case, I'm receiving a collection of flights. The property FLDATE, which is the date of which the airplane leaves, is now a `date` property. I'd like to convert it to a `string` property. I'm unsure if the code is correct or not because my Javascript knowledge is limited. What do you think of the following function?

```
function changeCollection (colIn)
{
    var theList = new Collection();
    for(var i = 0; i < colIn.length; i++)
    {
        var colItem = colIn[i];
        colItem.FLDATE = colItem.FLDATE.toString();
        theList[i] = colItem;
    }
    return theList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine. But if you don't need to keep the original array, you can make changes in place:

```
function changeCollection (colIn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < colIn.length; i++) {
        colIn[i].FLDATE = colIn[i].FLDATE.toString();
    }
}
```

Or you can use library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) to make it more readable:

```
_(colIn).each(function (flight) {
  flight.FLDATE = flight.FLDATE.toString();
});
```

Note that I've not run this code, so it may contain some typos.